# (Blogdown) R Markdown Blog Post Doesn't Work

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I created a *blogdown* website by doing `blogdown::new_site()`. It appears that the *Markdown* posts work perfectly fine but the *R Markdown* posts do not appear when I preview my site with `blogdown::serve_site()`. The R Markdown post is written in a file called index.Rmd, but it doesn't appear in the website. All of the index.md files do appear as blog posts though. It should look like [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html#fig%3Alithium=).
As you can see, there is a post from 2020, one from 2016, and one from 2015.
For me, only the 2016 and 2015 posts appear as they are written in *Markdown*.
The 2020 post does not appear for me as it is written in *R Markdown*.

Running `blogdown::check_site()` gave me this output:

```
> blogdown::check_site()
― Running a series of automated checks for your blogdown website project...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
○ A successful check looks like this.
● [TODO] A check that needs your attention looks like this.
| Let's check out your blogdown site!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
― Checking config.yaml
| Checking "baseURL" setting for Hugo...
● [TODO] Update "baseURL" to your actual URL when ready to publish.
| Checking "ignoreFiles" setting for Hugo...
○ "ignoreFiles" looks good - nothing to do here!
| Checking setting for Hugo's Markdown renderer...
○ All set! Found the "unsafe" setting for goldmark.
― Check complete: config.yaml

― Checking .gitignore
● [TODO] .gitignore was not found. You may want to add this.
― Checking Hugo
| Checking Hugo version...
○ Found Hugo. You are using Hugo 0.97.1.
| Checking .Rprofile for Hugo version used by blogdown...
○ blogdown is using Hugo 0.97.1 to build site locally.
― Check complete: Hugo

― Checking netlify.toml...
○ Found HUGO_VERSION = 0.97.1 in [build] context of netlify.toml.
| Checking that remote & local Hugo versions match...
○ It's a match! Local and remote Hugo versions are identical (0.97.1).
| Checking that Netlify & local Hugo publish directories match...
○ Good to go - blogdown and Netlify are using the same publish directory: public
― Check complete: netlify.toml

― Checking content files
| Checking for validity of YAML metadata in posts...
○ All YAML metadata appears to be syntactically valid.
| Checking for previewed content that will not be published...
○ Found 0 files with future publish dates.
○ Found 0 files marked as drafts.
| Checking your R Markdown content...
● [TODO] Found 1 R Markdown file to render:

  content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd

  To render a file, knit or use blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = 'newfile')
○ All R Markdown output files are up to date with their source files.
| Checking for .html/.md files to clean up...
○ Found 0 duplicate .html output files.
○ Found 0 incompatible .html files to clean up.
| Checking for the unnecessary 'content/' directory in theme...
○ Great! Your theme does not contain the content/ directory.
― Check complete: Content
```

It says, "To render a file, knit or use blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = 'newfile')".
So I ran `blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = 'newfile')`:

```
> blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = 'newfile')
Rendering content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd... Quitting from lines 30-37 (index.Rmd)
Error in text.default(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, adj = ifelse(P$x <  :
  X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 12 could not be loaded
Calls: local ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> pie -> text -> text.default
Execution halted
Error: Failed to render content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd
Execution halted
```

Here is the output of `xfun::session_info('blogdown')`:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Gentoo GNU/Linux

Locale:
  LC_CTYPE=en_CA.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C
  LC_TIME=en_CA.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.utf8
  LC_MONETARY=en_CA.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=C
  LC_PAPER=en_CA.utf8       LC_NAME=C
  LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C
  LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3  blogdown_1.9     bookdown_0.26    bslib_0.3.1
  digest_0.6.29    evaluate_0.15    fastmap_1.1.0    fs_1.5.2
  glue_1.6.2       graphics_4.1.2   grDevices_4.1.2  highr_0.9
  htmltools_0.5.2  httpuv_1.6.5     jquerylib_0.1.4  jsonlite_1.8.0
  knitr_1.38       later_1.3.0      magrittr_2.0.3   methods_4.1.2
  mime_0.12        promises_1.2.0.1 R6_2.5.1         rappdirs_0.3.3
  Rcpp_1.0.8.3     rlang_1.0.2      rmarkdown_2.13   sass_0.4.1
  servr_0.24       stats_4.1.2      stringi_1.7.6    stringr_1.4.0
  tinytex_0.38     tools_4.1.2      utils_4.1.2      xfun_0.30
  yaml_2.3.5

Hugo version: 0.97.1
```

Finally, here is a repository for my website so you can test it for yourselves:
https://github.com/Amarakon55/amarakon.com

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue, and after trying many different things (re-installing RStudio, Hugo, cleaning the R caches, ...), what ended up working was deleting my `.Rprofile`!
Let me know if that works for you.